# If statements using a checkbox in HTML/Javascript

Tags: python

I am attempting to find the value of variable x and variable y, but i can not get it to divide properly. I always get an error involving the z variable.

```
x = str(input("What was your total: "))
y = str(input("What percentage of a tip would you like to give (15 or 20): "))
z = float(x / y)

print("The tip you will want to give will be: " + z)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are strings. You can't divide them.

Comment: z = float(x / y)     TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected version:

```
x = int(str(input("What was your total: ")))
y = int(str(input("What percentage of a tip would you like to give (15 or 20): ")))
z = float(x / y)

print("The tip you will want to give will be:", z)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: And of course, (x / y) is the wrong formula...